# How do I unlock the rest of the developer options?

Tags: android

I got an Android phone that I wanted to use for development. I unlocked the developer options; however, the options appear to be incomplete. It only contains **Stay awake**, **USB debugging**, and **Allow mock locations**. The other options are missing.

It's a Lenovo A536 running Android Kitkat.

Edit: I tried enabling USB debugging mode, but nothing appeared.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about setting the Debug options on the device, not about programming.

Comment: you can try this application to access the full developer options https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.selfip.unet.developer_options

Comment: It's possible (and useful) but I was lucky and I can't reproduced it!!